# Declare Pyspark variable in Synapse and use it in Kusto query

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-data-explorer, azure-synapse

I want to declare Pyspark variable in Synapse and use the variable in Kusto queries.

The variable declared in Pyspark as below

```
s = "02-01-2022"
print(s)
e = "02-10-2022"
print(e)
```

Want to use the variable '`s`' and '`e`' in Kusto queries as shown below

```
%%pyspark

s = "02-01-2022" 
print(s)
e = "02-10-2022"
print(e)

# Read data from Azure Data Explorer table(s)
# Full Sample Code available at: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/master/samples/src/main/python/SynapseSample.py

sales_data  = spark.read \
    .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.synapse.datasource") \
    .option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "LinkedServiceName") \
    .option("kustoDatabase", "DatabaseName") \
    .option("kustoQuery", "let starttime = startofday(todatetime('s')); let endtime = startofday(todatetime('e')); Table | where Time between (starttime .. endtime)  | summarize amount = count() by Date= bin(TIMESTAMP,5h) | project Date,amount | order by Date asc") \
    .load()

display(sales_data)
```

Comment: What is the challenge here? Wont string appending work to replace `s` with its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the variable in the following way in pyspark:

```
option("kustoQuery", "let starttime = startofday(todatetime('" + s + "')); let endtime = startofday(todatetime('" + e + "')); Table | where Time between (starttime .. endtime)  | summarize amount = count() by Date= bin(TIMESTAMP,5h) | project Date,amount | order by Date asc")
```

Also, please refer [Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) connector for Apache Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/data-sources/apache-spark-kusto-connector#:%7E:text=The%20Azure%20Data%20Explorer%20(Kusto)%20connector%20is%20currently%20only%20supported,Synapse%20Apache%20Spark%202.4%20runtime.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.